# RxQuality in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, core-telephony

can we access RxQuality in iPhone application when user make a call.I want to do it for JailBreak.

i am able to access signal strength though following code

```
int getSignalStrength()
{
    void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LAZY);
    int (*CTGetSignalStrength)();
    CTGetSignalStrength = dlsym(libHandle, "CTGetSignalStrength");
    if( CTGetSignalStrength == NULL) 
        NSLog(@"Could not find CTGetSignalStrength");   
    int result = CTGetSignalStrength();
    dlclose(libHandle); 
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jan, did you already find a mapping between the integer value and the signal level in dBm?

Should be something between -113 and -51 dBm for 2G (GSM/EDGE) and -120..-25 dBm for 3G (UMTS/HSxPA).

Answer (score 0):

for testing signal strength u can use this link [signal test](https://github.com/valexa/VAFieldTest)

It may work for both jailbroken and non-jail-broken.